# How to get column for idxmax and idxmin even when data is missing?

Tags: python, pandas

For the following code, I would expect that I also get with missing data (like with `df2`) the columns `highDate` and `lowDate` that comprise the value where the referring max and min values occur in the resampled data.

What do I have to do to get the points in time where the min and max happened even when some data is missing after resampling (or is there any alternative to `idxmin` and `idxmax`)?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)

amountOfDataPoints = 12
myRange1 = pd.date_range('2018-04-09', periods=amountOfDataPoints, freq='1min')
myRange2 = pd.date_range('2018-04-09', periods=amountOfDataPoints, freq='1h')

data = np.random.rand(amountOfDataPoints)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, myRange1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, myRange2)

df1Resampled = df1.resample('10min', label='right').agg({
    'high': 'max',
    'highDate': 'idxmax',
    'low': 'min',
    'lowDate': 'idxmin'
})

df2Resampled = df2.resample('10min', label='right').agg({
    'high': 'max',
    'highDate': 'idxmax',
    'low': 'min',
    'lowDate': 'idxmin'
})

df1Resampled.head()
Out[3]: 
                         high            highDate       low             lowDate
                            0                   0         0                   0
2018-04-09 00:10:00  0.720324 2018-04-09 00:01:00  0.000114 2018-04-09 00:02:00
2018-04-09 00:20:00  0.685220 2018-04-09 00:11:00  0.419195 2018-04-09 00:10:00


df2Resampled.head()
Out[4]: 
                         high       low
                            0         0
2018-04-09 00:10:00  0.417022  0.417022
2018-04-09 00:20:00       NaN       NaN
2018-04-09 00:30:00       NaN       NaN
2018-04-09 00:40:00       NaN       NaN
2018-04-09 00:50:00       NaN       NaN
```

Comment: `idxmax` ignores `na` by default. What exactly do you want?

Comment: Thanks four your reply. I would like to have also for df2Resampled the two idxmin/idxmax columns in the reply. And filled where high and low are != NaN. Do I  understand it correctly, that the parameter `skipna=False` (see: [idxmax documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) ) would achieve what I want? But how do I supply it in the aggregate function?